# Настройка компонента Timer

Tags: c#, .net

Скажите, в VS есть компонент Timer, там вот у него есть 1 событие `Timer1_Tick`, так вот я не совсем понял, когда оно срабатывает?

И второй вопрос, поле Interval, я не совсем понял, как его правильно заполнить... ввожу 1000 - он срабатывает каждую секунду, ввожу 10000 - срабатывает только 1 раз...

Comment: По второму вопросу, событие будет выполняться раз в 10 секунд.
Возможно вы просто не дождались второго срабатывания. Проверьте.

Answer (score 2):

Событие, привязанное к `Timer_tick` будет выполняться один раз за интервал. Интервал считается в миллисекундах. (т.е. `interval`=1000 это 1 секунда)

Собственно, на msdn это [все есть](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx#Y0).

Рабочий код:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TimerTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int timer = 0;
    private bool flag=false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer++;
        lTimer.Text = timer.ToString();
    }

    private void bStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag == false)
        {
            flag = true;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
            timer++;
        }
            else
            {
            timer1.Stop();
            timer1.Enabled= false;
            flag = false;
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Но вот вопрос, у меня есть переменная timer(типа int), и каждые 10 секунд она должна увеличиваться на 1.... но это почему-то происходит только один раз, а потом я ждал 3 минуты, и она больше не увеличивалась. Вот код по которому я пытался увеличить переменную(мало ли может быть неправильно)

    timer++;

Comment: Такс.
По timer++ я вам ничего не расскажу.
Полный код timer_tick в студию.

upd: Ладно, предположим, что вы работаете с формой.
Должно быть так:

1) Объявлена глобальная переменная timer:
private int timer=0;
2) При инициализации формы происходит присвоение переменной timer значения 0.
3) В timer_tick пишете
timer++;
// вывод переменной timer на форму
4) Да, разумеется таймер надо запустить.
Предположим, что делается это по нажатии на какую-нибудь кнопку:
timer.enabled = true;
timer.start();

Проверяете.

Comment: А у меня почему-то не работает... скажите у вас есть скайп? Просто у меня немного другое предназначение для таймера... Легче рассказать и показать.

Comment: Нет, извините, скайп я свой не дам )).
Лучше попробуйте объяснить суть проблемы, все-таки хэшкод и создан для того, чтобы решать проблемы. (если, конечно, в вашем коде нет ничего сверхсекретного)

Comment: в событие bStart_Click следует в самом начале добавить строчку:  flag = !flag;

Comment: @krupennikov, зачем?

Comment: А для чего тогда переменная flag? И она всегда будет равна false. Судя по коду при одном нажатие на кнопку таймер запускается, при следующем нажатие - останавливается. Либо здесь не весь код...

Comment: Лол, я и не заметил. Спасибо.

Comment: что за индусы писали? 
    
    if(flag == false)

почему не 

    if(!flag)

плюс ``private bool flag=false;`` и ``private bool flag;`` эквиваленты